# Can you create a 32-bit AppDomain from a 64-bit process?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

Is it possible to create an AppDomain to host/run some 32-bit code from a 64-bit process, and then be able to pass/marshal data from the newly created AppDomain to host AppDomain?

I could do this as an out-of-process executable, but I am trying to avoid having a large binary foot-print for the 32-bit process (which happens to be a stand-alone .NET 6.0 console executable).

Comment: You'd have a large footprint only if you created two single-file executables. Otherwise you'd be able to store the files needed by both applications in the same folder. You'd have to take care to use different config files

Comment: it is .NET 6.0, so the answetr is no, simply because there aren't AppDomains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't half on the same process to run as 64 bit and the other as 32 bit. So even if .Net 6 would support creating AppDomains ([which it does not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable#application-domains)) creating 32bit AppDomain in 64bit process would not work.

You need to create separate processes for that which may share most of the code /binaries - you only need bootstraping app to be explicitly 32 or 64 bits, the rest of your assemblies can be "Any".

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for away to avoid out-of-process, but it was a reach...